# How to solve for Rn with inequality that has factorial

Tags: calculus, inequality

The inequality:
$1000 ≤ (n+1)!$

After comparing the answer from this particular problem via Slader & Chegg, it seems both people posting the solutions skipped this step.

According to both posts, the solution ends up like this:
~ $ 7  ≤ n+1$

$6$ terms for accuracy up to $0.001$

How did they get the ~$7 ≤ n+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why this is true observe that $n! < (n+1)!$ which means if $n<m$ then $n! < m!$ and $6! = 720 < 1000$ thus $n>6$ or $n \ge 7$

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was thinking myself.

Comment: I am glad that this helped